# How to reduce the resolution of an Image in Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt

I'm making a program whose purpose is to compare to images to see if they are equal, even if they have different resolutions, the program works fine when I have the same image with the same resolution, but when I have different resolutions it does not work, the problem might be the step where I rescale the images, is there anyway I can rescale the images along with their resolutions so I can make them equals?

My function to load the first image (I do the same process to load the second one)

```
//load Images
void MainWindow::loadNewImage(QString fileName)
{
    QPixmap image(fileName);
    auto img2(image.scaled(WITH,HEIGHT));
    ui->image2->setPixmap(img2);
}
```

My comparator function

```
            for(int i(0);i<newImg.size().width();i++)
            {
                for(int j(0);j<newImg.size().height();j++)
                {
                    QColor coloring(newImg.pixelColor(i,j));
                    QColor coloring2(currImg.pixelColor(i,j));
                    if(coloring2==coloring)
                    {
                        isEqual=true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        isEqual=false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

I've already tried: the scale function
`auto img2(image.scaled(WITH,HEIGHT));`

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that unless you control the scaling, and do it identically for both images, no, you're not going to get a pixel-per-pixel identical image to compare.

As a possible route toward something that could work, I'd probably pre-process both to roughly similar brightness and contrast. So find the darkest, brightest, and average pixel values in each, and adjust one so the two are roughly the same.

Then go through and sum the absolute differences between pixels, and divide by the number of pixels, to get an average error per pixel. With some experimentation, you can probably come up with a threshold of difference you'll tolerate, and still consider them the same (but offhand, I'm not sure what threshold you'll be happy with).

But even without scaling, even trivial differences in brightness, contrast, saturation, etc., can and will show differences even between images that are clearly the same. For example consider these two:

[image]

[image]

Obviously the same image. And exactly the same size. But if you just compare values of pixels, there are definitely differences.